# Running a delayed command with 'sudo'

Tags: bash, sudo, gnu-coreutils

I want run a Bash script as *root*, but delayed. How can I achieve this?

```
sudo "sleep 3600; command" , or
sudo (sleep 3600; command)
```

does not work.

Comment: I don't understand answers below suggesting `cron`, which is used for *regularly* scheduled events on the server. If you want to perform an action just once, then `at` is a *much* better choice.

Comment: Sure. Therefore I accpeted the answer with _at_. :)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can use [at](https://linux.die.net/man/1/at):

```
sudo at next hour
```

And then you have to enter the command and close the file with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>. Alternatively you can specify commands to be run in a file:

```
sudo at -f commands next hour
```

Comment: Yes, because for the superuser cron is preferred.

Answer (score 4):

If you really must avoid using [cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron):

```
sudo sh -c "(sleep 3600; command)&"
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest answer is:

```
sudo bash -c 'sleep 3600; command' &
```

Because `sleep` is a shell command and not an executable, and the semicolon is a shell “operator” too, it is a shell script, and hence needs to run in a shell. `bash -c` tells `sudo` to run `bash` and pass it a script to execute as a string.

Of course this will “hang” until `command` has actually finished running, or be killed if you exit the surrounding shell. I haven’t found a simple way to use `nohup` to prevent that here, and at that point, you’re basically reimplementing the `at` command anyway. I have found the above solution useful in many simple cases though. ;)

**For anything more complex…** of course you can always make a real shell script file, with a shebang (`#! …`) at the start, and run that. But I assume the whole point is that you wanted to avoid this for something that simple.

You could theoretically pass a string as a file using Bash’s `… <( … )` syntax, but `sudo` expects it to be a real file, and marked as executable too, so that won’t work.

Answer (score -2):

Use:

```
sleep 3600; sudo <command>
```

Anyway, I would consider using [cron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) in your case…

Comment: this will ask password after a hour - i want enter the password now

Comment: In such case I think chrisdowney pretty much nailed it below. You could also use `sudo bash -c 'sleep 3600; command'`